# I cant perform mvn release:prepare

Tags: maven, tfs, release, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to perform mvn release:prepare  with tfs and got error:

```
 Command line - cmd.exe /X /C "tf status -login:[domain]\[username],null -workspace:workspace -recursive -format:detailed [pathToTheProject]"
[INFO] err - TF30063: You are not authorized to access [serverName].
```

I suspect that maven have problem with recognizing password or maybe I set my developerConnection wrong
My Scm:

```
<scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:tfs:[domain]\\[username];[password]http[s]://server_name:workspace:$/TeamProject/Path/To/Project</developerConnection>
    <url>[domain]\\[username];[password]http[s]://server_name:workspace:$/TeamProject/Path/To/Project</url>
  </scm>
```

My build tag in maven:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-tfs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-tfs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Check that connection and developerConnection is correctly configured...Furthermore maven-scm-plugin and the maven-scm-providers should be in line using the same versions...Check debug output if the connection information are corretly picked up...(I have given up to use TFS in relationship with maven-release-plugin; Might be caused by strange TFS setup).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on your TFS config. But if you get an authentication failure for the SCM server, then you are probably lacking an entry like this for the server:

```
<server>
    <id>myServer</id>
    <username>theUserId</username>
    <password>{encryptedPassword}</password>
</server>
```

This should be set in the settings.xml file used by your build server running your maven builds.
Check out the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html) on how to encrypt your passwords.

Comment: Thank you for answer. It seemed very logical and I added this tag in settings file but it didnt help, I have the same error. I think that maven dont recognize password becouse you see there is null value after username in error message. :(

Comment: @Spasoje, and the `<id>` does match your server name?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [SCM URL](https://maven.apache.org/scm/tfs.html) below:

```
scm:tfs:[[domain\\]username[;password]@]http[s]://server_name[:port][:isCheckinPoliciesEnabled]:workspace:$/TeamProject/Path/To/Project
```

Answer (score 0):

You would get an Access Denied error if maven were not able to authenticate. Instead you get a TF30063 which is mostly related to a permission issue: have you checked that the user authenticating with TFS has read permission to the TFS version control?

Comment: I have privileges to read and write to tfs for sure, I was checking in and checking out many times with this user.

Comment: Can you look at the IIS logs on the TFS server? or capture the traffic using NetMon, Wireshark or Fiddler? This will clarify the sequence of HTTP interchange and the response codes.
Is TFS configured for NTLM, Kerberos or Basic Auth? Maven is configured accordingly?